# Upgrade Ckeditor without hassle

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I came up with a decision to use `CKEditor` into my application. However, I have a thing to make sure in terms of upgrading `CKEditor` into latest version in the near future.

I'm going to made some custom changes in image plugin provided by default. If i do changes in `/ckeditor/plugins/image/plugin.js` then I'll be affected by upgrade process.

Is there any alternative way to do change just like custom configuration

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editorId', {
    customConfig: '/custom/ckeditor_config.js'
});
```

through external file in `CKEditor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make changes to a library, you can't sanely upgrade. That is why if a library doesn't suit a large portion of your needs, you can't really use it.

If they are something that CKEditor as a whole can actually make use of, you can create a pull request and ask your improvements integrated into actual CKEditor, if not, you'll have to either not upgrade, or not do your improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to what Second Rikudo wrote, you can maintain a fork of [CKEditor](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev). If the changes that you're planning to do are not too deep you should not have any troubles with merging changes in the CKEditor code base back to your fork. The image plugin for instance is very stable right now and there were only few small [changes made last year](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/commits/master/plugins/image/plugin.js).

Many developers maintain their forks of CKEditor and if you're not planning to rewrite entire plugin I recommend this way.

However, if you're planning to make deep changes in the image plugin, the better way will be to create new plugin based on the original image plugin. This way you'll be able to get updates for the core of CKEditor and other plugins without any conflicts with your changes.